# Best way to see if an entity exists in the database given a condition in Grails/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

What is the best way to see if an entity/domain is already existing in the database given a condition? Wherein the conditions are checked against the attributes of the entity/domain.

The straight forward way is to query them and check, but in my case, I just need to see if one entity satisfies a condition. So I was thinking if there is a another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could issue a query that just returns a count...

```
Person.where {
    name == 'Jeff'
}.count()
```

That doesn't actually retrieve `Person` instances.  It sends a query to the database that returns the number of instances.  For example, if you were using GORM with Hibernate, the generated SQL might look something like this...

```
select count(*) as y0_ from person this_ where this_.name=?
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Verifying existence without pulling the data out.

Comment: I understand that this scans the whole table to be able to count all of the entities, is there a way to make it stop scanning when it finds one? Is there a way to do something like "select count(*) from (select * from table_x where field=1 limit 1) as x" in GORM?

Comment: try .exists() instead

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do `Person.countByName('Manuel')`